# VBA Error I dont know how I can fix

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm Currently programming something for my IT Teacher in PowerPoint VBA and its not kinda my thing, my thing is VisualBasic.net, Java, C++, F#, Anything advanced is what I'm into, Direct X for example, but this error is so simple it's killing my brain that I cant find it, can you help me.

```
Public Function IncrementValueBeta(SlideDescription As String, SlideNumber As Integer, SlideName As String)
    ChangeSlide (SlideNumber)
    MsgBox ("Test")
End Function
```

It's currently unfinished but I call it by using

`IncrementValueBeta("Intro", 1, "Slide1")`

But the Error I get is "Syntax Error" or "Expected `=`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the ChangeSlide method exists?  Did you put Option Explicit at the top of your module?  That will help identify if VBA thinks you're declaring a variable implicitly when you thought you were using something that already existed.

A few ideas:
1. Since you're not returning anything, you should be using a Sub.
2. Once you've converted it to a Sub, the parentheses around the parameters are not needed.  (In fact VBA tried to help indicate that by adding the space between the method call and the parameter)

Try:

```
Public Sub IncrementValueBeta(SlideDescription As String, SlideNumber As Integer, SlideName As String)
    ChangeSlide  SlideNumber
    MsgBox  "Test"
End Sub
```

Then you'd call it as:

```
IncrementValueBeta "Intro", 1, "Slide1"
```

I'm not seeing where you're using the description, or slide name so perhaps you could remove those parameters.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, ive made it 
   Public Function ChangeSlide(NewSlide As Integer)
       ' Changes Slide
       ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (NewSlide)
   End Function

+ i think its the Arguments, ill just make a new way. P.s. can you make a string eg.  SlideN = string then use it like IncrementValue("Slide3") and in the Code it will do Slide3.ClickedTimes.Caption = bah bah?

Comment: and Thanks :) you Fixed the Problem i think it was because i was using ("Intro", 1, "Slide1") oh and to the bit where you was saying i wasnt you'sing the other values, i wasnt programmed there because i couldent access it so i make them else where, so i could test them and add them in after, you know.

Comment: If removing the parentheses fixed the problem, please check the "answer" checkbox.  I can't quite make out your other question from the comments - you should search around and if you can't find an answer just ask a new question.

Comment: Lol ok sorry, im the worst at describing stuff and Thanks :)